# How to connect between local Python files?

Tags: python, class, import, circular-dependency

I have a project that I am working on and in this project there is a *gui.py* file and in it a class called `HomePgae`. In a separate Python file there is a class called *Global * which I use to store data of the project, such as paths, constant variables of the whole project etc. I want to store my HomePage object in this class as well, but because I use the `Global` class in the `HomePage` object, this creates a problem.

When I tried to import each class in each Python file I received a circular import error. Even when I try to merge the files into one file, the system does not recognize one of the classes (depending on which one is before the other).

Does anyone know what to do about this?

I don't even know if this is the correct and accepted way to split classes into different files in a python project. I hope to get some guidance here.

Comment: You can import the neccesary functions when needed. For example, if you need the members from `Global` during a function in `HomePage`, you can import `Global` inside that function rather than at the top of the file